# generar una matriz aleatoria entre 10 y 9999 en interfaz grafica java

Tags: java, matrices, jframe

estoy aprendiendo y estoy resolviendo un problema que al darle click a un botón genere una matriz con números aleatorios en 10 y 9999. el error viene del metodo generar matriz ademas creo que estoy pasando mal el tamaño de la matriz

```
 private void btnGenerarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        //boton generar 
        int n = Integer.parseInt(txtN.getText());
        int matriz[][] = new int [n][n];
        matriz = this.generarMatriz(n);
        this.mostrarMatriz(matriz, n);
        
    }    
public void mostrarMatriz (int matriz[][], int n){
       
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tablaMatriz.getModel();
        //le paso la cantidad de filas
        model.setRowCount(n);
        //le paso la cantidad de columnas 
        model.setColumnCount(n);
        //ahora colocare cada valor de la matriz en el JTable
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            //filas
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                //con el setValueAt se mostrara los valor de la matriz en el JTable
                tablaMatriz.setValueAt(matriz[i][j], i, j);
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    public int[][] generarMatriz(int n){
    int matriz[][] =new int [n][n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<n;j++){
            matriz[i][j]=(int) (Math.random()*(10-9999)+10);
        }
    }
    return matriz;
    }
```

el error es:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at matripack.matrices.generarMatriz(matrices.java:227)
    at matripack.matrices.btnGenerarActionPerformed(matrices.java:155)
```

en la linea de  `matriz[i][j]=(int) (Math.random()*(10-9999)+10);`  y en   `matriz = this.generarMatriz(n);`

Comment: ¿cuál es el error y en que línea se produce?

Comment: se produce en `matriz[i][j]=(int) (Math.random()*(10-9999)+10);` y en ` matriz = this.generarMatriz(n);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es simple, tienes mal tu segundo `for` del metodo `generarMatriz(int n)`

```
 for(int j=0;i<n;j++){
```

En el condicional del `for` tienes `i < n` en vez de `j < n`

Quedaría así:

```
 int matriz[][] =new int [n][n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                  //^^ aqui tenias i
            matriz[i][j]=(int) (Math.random()*(10-9999)+10);
        }
    }
    return matriz;
}
```

Comment: gracias, a veces por errores simples te puedes volver loco